How does the "earthing" system works in a UPS
PLEASE SEE EDIT 1
I want to know how exactly the earthing system works in a UPS, an example with by the ECOFlow RIVER 2. From their webpage it seems so simple, you charge the battery, switch the AC, and then plug your device into it. However what about the safety of this, since you are now essentially bypassing your DB protection?
For example let's take the case of the DC input source, that is used to charge and power the AC load.

Now from my understanding in a traditional household the "Grid" electrical system is like this:

Does this then mean if I want to use the UPS in a "safe" manner I need to implement the below:

Where I bring up the LIVE, NEUTRAL, and EARTH from the AC mains 3-pin plug, go to a mini DB box and install the RCD, and breaker, and also use an earth rod to properly earth the system?

Secondly, where is the EARTH from the three-pin receptacle on the device internally connected to?
Edit 1:
User manual: Manual
In addition if the below happens, will I get shocked or worse die?


There is no user manual linked on their site. That's a red flag.

@Transistor Seems to be a "User manual" link in the footer of the page, but that goes to a whole library of documents (16 pages of 9 listings) and videos. OP better search through an give us the link to the relevant one.

1: The flow chart is not necessarily how /all/ residential distribution panels are wired. In Norway I don't think I've ever come across a breaker panel that doesn't break both liver and neutral. 2: The UPS should absolutely give you the correct safe wiring in an operating/installation manual. Especially since they're so insistent on how TÜV strict regulation approved their product is...

@MrGerber see edit 1

@Transistor see edit 1

@MrGerber This is the first time I hear about a residential system somewhere that does cut the neutral. And I am familiar with many different systems so far. Can you point to a source?

@Justme I would have to refer to the Norwegian electrical code, and I don't think its available without paywall, and the one I have is way too old, but there is an explanation from the norwegian NEC in the changelog for the 5. edition, and it says that there is no requirement for all-pole protection in TN systems, but the neutral conductor shall be disconnected, and in 1-phase installations, a 1P+N protector is compliant, as it disconnects the N. The comittee state that they are clear on the fact that tey recommend two pole protection as stated in their guidance. 1/x

2/x "Overcurrent protectors 2P and 1P+N will both comply with the requirements given in NEK 400-4-43:2014, section 431.2.1 and NEK 400-5-53:2014, section 537.2.1.1. Overcurrent protectors 1P will not comply with the requirements unless there exists an upstream all-pole disconnection switch"

@Justme Link to the source for the lastest quote: https://www.nek.no/standarder/produkter/tolkninger-nek-400/#5.-utgave-(2014-2018)
